# How to change movement axis?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

I need help, how do I make it move the same way its rotated? The arrows are the same orientation as always, I need to make it accustomed to the orientation of the object itself.

Comment: I use 'gx' for instance to grab on the x axis or g<shift>Z to grab on x and y.  I often use gxx or gyy to grab along the normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Tranform Orientations* panel, choose *Local* instead of *Global* (shortcut ","):

[image]

Also you can simply press <kbd>G</kbd> and double X, Y or Z if you want to move the object along its own axis.

Answer (score 3):

change that to local. That defines the axis. As long as you don't apply rotation you will always be able to move it the way you'd expect.
[image]